Flutter FirebaseAuth prevent Firebased from forcing logout
I have an app using Firebase Auth, iOS native, and the last build dates back 3 years ago. We used to save the refresh token to avoid having the user login every time the token expired.
I am porting it to Flutter, and the documentation says that on mobile, I have nothing to do for this to work. However, this does not seem to be accurate. I am currently developing the app, and every day when I return to work in the morning, I have to log back in. This is not how we want it to be. The requirements are that the user only needs to log in if they explicitly log out from the app. It does not seem possible anymore to save the token on mobile to automatically log the user back in. I am uncertain if this issue is occurring because the app is still in debug mode or if Firebase is logging out users overnight.
Or maybe something I have not initialized ??
I do have this in my Main() function
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);

I tried to find information on this but there is no solution as everything always comes back to "Firebase automates this". if it is the case it is not doing a great job at it.
EDIT:
@riverpod
class FirebaseAuthStateNotifier extends _$FirebaseAuthStateNotifier {
  late final StreamSubscription<User?> _authStateChangesSubscription;

  late StreamSubscription<User?> _userChangesSub;

  @override
  Future<User?> build() async {
    _authChanges();
    _userChanges();

    ref.onDispose(() {
      _authStateChangesSubscription.cancel();
      _userChangesSub.cancel();
    });
    var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    await user?.reload();
    return user;
  }

  void _userChanges() {
    _userChangesSub = FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().listen((User? user) {
      if (user == null) {
        log('userChanges: User is currently signed out!');
      } else {
        log('userChanges: User is signed in!');
        //user.reload();
        state = AsyncValue.data(user);
      }
    });
  }

  void _authChanges() {
    _authStateChangesSubscription =
        FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
      if (user != null) {
        user.reload();
        //state = AsyncValue.data(user);
      } else {}
      state = AsyncValue.data(user);
    });
  }

  void signOut() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }

  void deleteCurrentUser() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.delete();
  }

  void sendEmailVerification() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.sendEmailVerification();
  }
}

and this is observed here in the main file in the scaffold
home: Center(
            child: authState.when(
                data: (user) {
                  var prefs = AppDelegate.prefs;
                  if (user == null) {
                    return const WelcomeLanding();
                  }
                  // check is email validation, if not got hold screen
                  //if valid and is new login go to onboarding.
                  return const EmailVerificationSwitch();
                },
                error: (error, stackTrace) => Text('Error: $error'),
                loading: () {
                  return const Text('Loading...');
                }),
          ),


Firebase Auth does indeed persist the token automatically for reuse.  But without seeing the code for your app, we can't tell what you might be doing wrong that prevents or circumvents this behavior.  If you're not using an auth state observer to track auth state changes, you're probably doing it wrong.

I have added the question witht he code that observes the changes.
